# Would it be better to handle request in global.asax?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, global-asax

I am making a simple request parses that takes in urls with querystring parameters and spits back xml.

Right now this is all handled in a default.aspx page, so I don't have to much around with url rewriting and such. Would it be better to keep the default.aspx page, but have the requests handled in the global.asax page?

Would it be more optimized that way?

Comment: Is it a performance bottleneck? If not, then this unusal approach might prove confusing to (a) anyone who has to maintain your code... (b) you in about two months!

Comment: I disagree, I think this would be a less confusing approach as it is handled in a central location.

Comment: Any method can be confusing...just make sure to comment your code well so anyone that needs to work on this doesn't need to hunt down any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For requests that don't need a full-blown ASP.NET page, you should take a look at the [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) interface, or just create [`ashx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) files.

Comment: Ya, that's what I meant. I was worried about the overhead of the page life cycle in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement a BasePage class that inherits System.Web.UI.Page then have all of my pages inherit BasePage.

Put in methods that you want to use through out the site in the base page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is what a HTTPHandler is designed for.  Here is the reference if you are unfamiliar:

[MSDN- HTTPHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)